# How to integrate paypal button that accepts credit cards and has specific label?

Tags: paypal

I have a website and want to add a PayPal button so that people can buy staff.

I want to:
1) Add a PayPal button to my website but I want it also TO ACCEPT CREDIT CARDS
2) Change the label. e.g.https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/buttons/

I have browsed dozens of explanations pages but they are all not focused and don't really prompt what to do.

Can anyone help hpw to do these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal has default settings where the credit card acceptance would be relative to your account/the button type/and a risk assessment. This might be something better to call in and speak with an agent who would have your account details.

Here is some sample code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pay Now">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><center>
<input type="text"   name="amount"><br>
</center></tr></td>
<tr><td><center>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</center></tr></td>
</table>
</form>
```

You would want to change this line:

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"
```

This is the image URL. If you change the URL there to the URL of the image you are looking to use than it will reflect on the site.

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great help. I have 2 more questions please: (1) how can I make the amout const (e.g. 10 USD)? (2) I need to pass some paraneters from my OWN form to my server. i.e. After the users pays, I have to send some data to my server fir processing. How can I do it?

Comment: If you are looking for something that comes back to your server than you may be better off looking into Express Checkout or IPN. When a user pays using a PayPal Standard button than there is no way to confirm payment without IPN. So for what you're wanting it will be a little more work.

Comment: As for the consistency, the line <input type="text"   name="amount"> can be changed to <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10"> and this line is currency <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">.

Comment: thsnk you very much for your answer. yrs, it seems that button will not be enough. could you please provide a link where i can read how to do it (since everything i read was a total mess...) thank you!

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

This is a link to what you are able to customize in your PayPal buttons.

Comment: Thank you, but since you said I will need Express Checkout or IPN, paypal button will not be relevant. Do you have such a link for Express Checkout or IPN? Thanks

Comment: IPN is an Instant Payment Notification which will send a message from PayPal to your server once the payment is completed (sense there is no way to ensure the buyer clicks "Return to merchant website". 

IPN overview information here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

PayPal Express Checkout is a little different. The payment completes on your server: This'll give you an overview:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

Comment: Thank you very much I will look it through